# Using PostSharp's Contracts support with AOP if possible?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, code-contracts

I have two questions that are related to Contracts and AOP using **PostSharp**:

*The built-in support for Code contracts that worked well with Visual Studio 2015 seems to have ended starting with Visual Studio 2017* (unfortunately in my opinion). So I'm not looking to use the Contracts from MS with PostSharp (unless that's possible using VS 2017)?

1.) So as an alternative, I was thinking whether it was possible to use the Contracts provided by PostSharp, and use it in conjunction with AOP?

I had previously been using PostSharp's AOP support in order to "inject" logging across my application as a way to clear the code of cross-cutting concerns, and that went really well I thought. ***I would like to add Contracts to my code in a similar manner if possible?***

I can see that it's possible to add contracts like so:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public void SetFullName([Required] string firstName, [Required] string lastName)
    {
        this.FullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

But to retroactively add "[Required]" to every relevant method in the entire code base feels like a drag :)

It seems that there’s no way to use PostSharp's AOP in conjunction with Contracts? Perhaps this is by design, since I can imagine that it’d be very hard to take into account all the various possibilities of different method signatures that existed. But nonetheless, I just wanted to make sure there wasn’t a "magic" way that made it possible, e.g. using AOP to automatically add a Contract.Requires(args != null) (but I understand that it’s hard to accomplish since you can’t apply the same contract to primitive data types etc.).

2.) Second question is that I couldn’t fnd an equivalent to Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null) or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To apply the PostSharp code contract aspect to multiple target elements at once you can employ [aspect provider](http://doc.postsharp.net/iaspectprovider) combined with [attribute multicasting](http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting). For example:

```
[PSerializable]
public class RequiredProviderAttribute : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        MethodBase targetMethod = (MethodBase) targetElement;
        ObjectConstruction contract = new ObjectConstruction(typeof(RequiredAttribute));

        foreach (var parameterInfo in targetMethod.GetParameters())
        {
            yield return new AspectInstance(parameterInfo, contract);
        }
    }
}

[RequiredProvider(AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method1(null);
    }

    private static void Method1(object a)
    {
        Method2(a);
    }

    // Contract is applied to the parameter of this method
    public static void Method2(object a)
    {

    }
}
```

2) PostSharp code contracts currently support only custom attributes syntax. To check the post-conditions you can however apply these custom attributes to the ref and out parameters and to the method return values. You can also implemented your own [custom code contracts](http://doc.postsharp.net/custom-contracts).

Comment: thanks for your answer and for the helpful links. It's possible that it works as intended, but I'm not entirely sure of the internal workings of PostSharp, so I just wanted to check with you if I got this correctly?

I've added the code just like you have in a Console app. If I add the RequiredProvider attribute on "Program", I get the "The parameter 'o' is required". If I remove the attribue, I get a normal "NullReferenceException", so that seems good. 

However, if I set a breakpoint in the "ProviderAspects" method, it's never hit? Is that by design or did I miss something?

Comment: (cont. from prev. comment). What I'm really after however, is that I'd like to add logging (possibly inside or together with ProviderAspects?) so that I could improve the logging so that it would (somehow) say:

"The parameter 'o' is required in Method2" (or something like that). Currently, the logger that I btw also am using with PostSharp's AOP, does not log what's inside ProvideAspects as well?  

But if that doesn't work, it's not a big deal, and I consider the above to be a nice improvement over not having any contracts in place at all... :)

Comment: The important detail here is that the ProvideAspects method is executed at *build time*. After C# compiler has produced the binary, PostSharp loads the file, executes the build-time aspect code and applies the transformations. Then the original binary is replaced with the transformed one. You can learn more about aspects lifetime at this link http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-lifetime